# Cause a javascript or javascripts to execute automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, dom-events

Hi I have a script which allows for downloads when the page is visited and link is clicked. I want to edit things so that once the link is clicked the download will start as specified the Javascripts but it will then start download and direct to a thank you page.
Here is an example:

1. Website visitor click the Download Link the Download Starts
2. Then website visitor is automatically redirected to a thank you page

The sample of the page and Javascript coding can be found here by inspecting the source code of the page http://www.mynetdownload.com/testdwld.html

Answer (score 1):

Once a download is starting, the 'current' page is the file that is downloading, so you will no longer have 'control' over the browser.

You should therefore reverse that;

1. Website visitor click the Download Link
2. Visitor goes to a 'thank you' page;
   *Thank you for downloading this file. Your download should start automatically. If the download does not start automatically, click the link below:
   [download link]*
3. The visitor is redirected to the file download

Because the 'download' is not shown *inside* the browser, the thank you page will remain visible during the download process.

Redirecting to the file-download can be done via a regular HTML redirect header in your `<head>`:

E.g. To have the download (redirect) start after 10 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/downloads/file1.zip">
```